# fatal Error when using pear pager !

Tags: php, pear

i used PEAR Pager in my Projects . it's works fine in my local server but when i upload it to hosing server it's gaves me fatal error :

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class PEAR_Common in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/Common.php on line 1123
```

i don't know what's the problem , how can i solve that ?!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. It seems like the class PEAR_Common is loaded twice. Check your code for includes/requires of this class.

If you are using other pear packages that might load (include) this class before you include your Pear_Pager class then this might be the problem.

Regards,

Comment: @andreas i moved pager require command to top of my config file before require any PEAR . but it dosen't work yet .

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot this without any additional info. andreas has given you the correct pointer.